# paste r commands inside rmarkdown file

Tags: regex, r, knitr, r-markdown

I want my function to place a piece of markdown in a readme.rmd file. However I would like to include some rcode that that will be executed when a new version of the readme file is rendered.

This is what I want in the readme.rmd:

`[![Last-changedate](https://img.shields.io/badge/last%20change-`r gsub("-", "--", Sys.Date())`-yellowgreen.svg)](/commits/master)"`

Which at knitr time will turn into a nicely formated shield with the date.

However to paste this in the document I have to escape some of the characters:

`` paste0("`r ", "gsub(\"-\", \"--\", Sys.Date())", "`") ``

But this results into

`` [![Last-changedate](https://img.shields.io/badge/last%20change-`r gsub(\"-\", \"--\", Sys.Date())`-yellowgreen.svg)](/commits/master)" ``

And this cannot be rendered by rmarkdown error: unexpected input: gsub(\ ^....

Comment: would using single quote works? i.e. use ``paste0("`r ", "gsub('-', '--', Sys.Date())", "`")``

Comment: Excellent suggestion! This worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the suggestion of [Chinsoon12](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1989480/chinsoon12):
" would using single quote works? i.e. use paste0("`r ", "gsub('-', '--', Sys.Date())", "`") "

My problem is solved!
I now paste with double and single quotes.

`` paste0("https://img.shields.io/badge/last%20change-",
                                    "`r ", "gsub('-', '--', Sys.Date())", "`",
                                    "-yellowgreen.svg") ``